# Match time with timezone between current time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have stored time in DB as time without time zone and I want cast this time to time with timezone and then compare it with current time.

```
WHERE (my_time::time AT TIME ZONE country_timezone)
      BETWEEN  (current_time::time) - 60 * INTERVAL '1 minute'
      AND (current_time::time) + 60 * INTERVAL '1 minute'
```

But the problem is that It is always compared against the time without time zone even after I casted It to time with timezone.

So for example

```
   'my_time' => string '18:00:00+09' (length=11)
   'current_time_plus' => string '10:51:47.997405'
   'current_time_minus' => string '09:51:47.997405'
```

This should not match, but since `my_time = 10:00:00` wihtout time zone then It is matching. How can I match the time as time with timezone ?

Comment: `60 * INTERVAL '1 minute'`?.. why not `interval '1 hour'`?..

Comment: also comparison looks wierd - why `time` and not `timestamp`?.. how can you tell whether `23:00` is more then `11:00`?.. if *more* means *later* then you need date as well, otherwise `23:00` can be earlier then `11:00`... Imaging you have `my_time = 23:30` then interval is `[22:30, 00:30]` and then lower bond in arythmetically bogger then higher

Comment: I am not sure with the time that I want to add yet, It will be probably in minutes so that is the reason for minute interval... Well I want to check periodically every 30 minutes or so and see if any time matches. Every time is saved in my current timezone and has timezone column next to It. So I just need time and not date, because every record will be proccesed once a day

Comment: then `interval 30 minutes` looks appropriate...

Comment: But there is still problem that the sql that I wrote is not comparing current time with the time modified with timezone but with time without timezone

Comment: because you cast `current_time::time`, not `current_time::timetz` I suppose

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not mixing times with time zone and without. I can't check myself but I assume

```
WHERE (my_time::time AT TIME ZONE country_timezone)
      BETWEEN  (current_time::timetz) - 60 * INTERVAL '1 minute'
      AND (current_time::timetz) + 60 * INTERVAL '1 minute'
```

should work. because after you `::time AT TIME ZONE` it becomes `timetz` and you compare it againt `timestamptz::time`, which gives you unexpected result

Comment: This still doesn't work even though the times have same format now.

Comment: please provide ddl and data sampe to reproduce. or post it somewhere on http://rextester.com or fiddle or anywhere

Comment: something like this http://rextester.com/RMNTO9673, the value in DB is in my current timezone and I want to select It only when it matches current_time when casted to time with timezone which should be then 18:00... I don't know why `testTime` is displayed with date but It doesn't do that in my script